# jquery slick carousel copy/paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I am using a slick carousel in a web page to pass through form data and info.

However I need to be able to select text inside the carousel. I thought that by setting draggable to false I would be able to select text, but the cursor shape changes to a text cursor but I still can not select text.

Is there a way around it?

I am configuring like this:

```
    $('.carousel').slick({
    prevArrow: '.btn-prev-cand',
    nextArrow: '.btn-next-cand',
    dots: false,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: true,
    accessibility: true,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    arrows: true,
    centerMode: false,
    variableWidth: false,
    draggable: false,
    swipeToSlide: false
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to override this in **css**

```
.slick-slider {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
.slick-list.draggable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

The problem that you described is a known issue - [Selecting/Highlighting text #826](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/826)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the setting "swipe" to false to disable the swiping and see the text cursor.

Comment: That didn't work wither. I could still not select/highlight text

Answer (score 0):

Colleague Martin's answer is great, but at the moment the text feature is supported in browsers, so there is no need at all to use moz webkit o

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#browser_compatibility

It is enough just to write

```
.slick-list.draggable 
{
  user-select: text;
}
```

Also, there is no need to write

```
.slick-list.draggable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

It is enough just to write the above code